# Ошибка при запросе с параметрами в Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Делаю что-то наподобие блога по туториалу, при чтении или удалении записи, получаю такую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Понимаю, что дело в параметрах, но решить проблему не могу
Код:
Контроллера

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(articles_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to '/'
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy!
    redirect_to 'root'
  end
end

private
def articles_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title,:text)
end
```

Вьюшек

```
new.erb
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :title%>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label :text %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :text%>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.submit%>
</p>
<% end %>

show.erb
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>

index.erb
<h1>Listing articles</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>
<%= link_to 'New Post', new_articles_path %>
  <% @article.each do |article| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= article.title %></td>
        <td><%= article.text %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', articles_path(article),controller: 'articles' %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', articles_path(article), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'  }%></td>

      </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Начальная Страница
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылки

```
<a href="/articles/new">New Post</a>
      <tr>
        <td>asdafsd</td>
        <td>asdasdczxc</td>
        <td><a controller="articles" href="/articles.1">Show</a></td>
        <td><a controller="articles" data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/articles.1">Destroy</a></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>sasdasdzxcxv</td>
        <td>dsfsvc</td>
        <td><a controller="articles" href="/articles.2">Show</a></td>
        <td><a controller="articles" data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/articles.2">Destroy</a></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>sasdasdzxcxv</td>
        <td>dsfsvcx</td>
        <td><a controller="articles" href="/articles.3">Show</a></td>
        <td><a controller="articles" data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/articles.3">Destroy</a></td>
```

Rake

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern              Controller#Action
 new_articles GET    /articles/new(.:format)  articles#new
edit_articles GET    /articles/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     articles GET    /articles(.:format)      articles#show
              PATCH  /articles(.:format)      articles#update
              PUT    /articles(.:format)      articles#update
              DELETE /articles(.:format)      articles#destroy
              POST   /articles(.:format)      articles#create
         root GET    /                        welcome#index
```

Comment: Попробуйте в строку `link_to 'Destroy'` добавить параметр `controller: 'articles'`, как в строке выше.

Comment: Это не работает, у меня стойкое впечатление, что при нажатии на ссылку show или destroy не передаются параметры, так как ошибка гласит "Couldn't find Article with 'id'=" где нет значения параметра :id,
я думаю что должно быть "Couldn't find Article with 'id'=5" или вроде того.
Добавил начальную страницу на всякий случай

Comment: @Lukashman откройте код страницы и посмотрите как выглядят ссылки. добавьте результат `rake routes` в вопрос.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman добавил.

Comment: @Lukashman еще добавьте `config/routes.rb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас написано `resource`, а надо `resources` (множественное число).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Заменил ресурсы в маршрутах, сперва правда не заработало, но я потом по логам понял, что нужно заменить во вьюшке индекса к ссылкам show и destroy articles_path(article) на article_path(article).
Стыдобища, из-за одной буквы себе столько мучений наделал.
Вы можете рассказать в чём различия resourse и resources, и в каких случаях они используются, я читал, что это изходит из RESTful services, но хотелось бы в таком случае знать побольше, большое спасибо заранее!

Comment: @Lukashman а вы сам Ruby хорошо знаете? Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: Ознакомился в общих чертах, перешел на него с Java, в любом случае, ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: @Lukashman лучше начните с Ruby, а потом уже переходите к Rails.